# Nest.js: Cannot read properties of undefined in case of property-based injection

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, nest

I'm new in Nest.js and wants to implement 'property-based injection' for my custom class.

```
# author.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthorService } from './author.service';
import { AuthorController } from './author.controller';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ConfigurationHelper } from 'src/tools/helpers/configuration-helper';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  controllers: [AuthorController],
  providers: [AuthorService, ConfigurationHelper],
})
export class AuthorModule {}
```

```
# author.controller.ts
...
  constructor(private readonly authorService: AuthorService) {}

  @Get()
  findAll() {
    return this.authorService.findAll();
  }
...
```

```
# author.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CustomException } from 'src/tools/helpers/custom-exceptions';

@Injectable()
export class AuthorService {
  constructor() {}

  findAll() {
    new CustomException('some message');
    return `This action returns all author`;
  }
}
```

```
# src/tools/helpers/custom-exceptions.ts
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigurationHelper } from './configuration-helper';

export class CustomException {
  @Inject()
  private readonly configurationHelper: ConfigurationHelper;
  
  constructor(myMsg: string) {
    const message = myMsg + this.configurationHelper.getEnv();
  }
}
```

```
# src/tools/helpers/configuration-helper.ts
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationHelper {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  getEnv(): string {
    return this.configService.get<string>('ENV');
  }
}
```

But when I call to endpoint, this error thrown:
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getEnv')
for this.configurationHelper. Looks like 'ConfigurationHelper' was not injected.

I did it based on documentation [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#property-based-injection)

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. if you call `new`, you're 100% in charge of everything in the class. Nest will do **no** injection for you
2. You can't use a property based injection property inside the constructor, event if Nest created the class for you, because the constructor has to finish running before Nest can assign any class properties to the instance

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, in the end, the execution flow looks like this:

```js
const foo = new CustomException()
foo.configurationHelper = new ConfigurationHelper()
```

so clearly you cannot use `configurationHelper` property in the constructor of `CustomException` classs

Instead you should use [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#usage) like `onModuleInit`